Finding the maximum of $\sqrt{|c-a|}+\sqrt{|a-b|}$.
Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers that satisfy the following,
$$\begin{cases}
\sqrt{|a-b|}+\sqrt{|b-c|}=20\\
\\
\sqrt{|b-c|}+\sqrt{|c-a|}=22\\
\end{cases}$$
If the maximum of $\sqrt{|c-a|}+\sqrt{|a-b|}$ is $p+q\sqrt{r}$ where $p,q$ are integers and $r$ is a square free integer.
Find $p+q\sqrt{r}$.

I first subtracted the equations to obtain $$\sqrt{|c-a|}-\sqrt{|a-b|}=2.$$ Squaring both sides yields, $$|c-a|+|a-b|-2\sqrt{|c-a||a-b|}=4 \tag{1}.$$
Suppose $\sqrt{|c-a|}+\sqrt{|a-b|}=k$, then after squaring we get $$k^{2}=|c-a|+|a-b|+2\sqrt{|c-a||a-b|}. \tag{2}$$
Substitute (1) into (2), $$k^{2}=4+4\sqrt{|c-a||a-b|} \tag{3}$$
What can I do from here?

Is the answer $p=46, q =-4, r = 22$?

As a matter of fact, yes! How'd you do it?

let
$$
X = \sqrt{|a-b|} \quad\quad
Y = \sqrt{|b-c|} \quad\quad
Z = \sqrt{|c-a|}
$$
In this way, the constraints can be rewritten in the following form:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\text{when} \\
\text{$a<b<c \quad$ or $\quad c<b<a$}\\
\end{array} \quad
\left\{\begin{aligned}
  X + Y &= 20 \\
 Y + Z &= 22 \\
 X^2 + Y^2 &= Z^2 \\
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\text{when} \\
\text{$b<c<a \quad$ or $\quad a<c<b$}\\
\end{array} \quad
\left\{\begin{aligned}
  X + Y &= 20 \\
 Y + Z &= 22 \\
 X^2 - Y^2 &= Z^2 \\
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\text{when} \\
\text{$b<a<c \quad$ or $\quad c<a<b$}\\
\end{array} \quad
\left\{\begin{aligned}
  X + Y &= 20 \\
 Y + Z &= 22 \\
 Y^2 - X^2 &= Z^2\\
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Next, solve those three groups of equations, we can arrive the maximum from the first situation (i.e. $X^2 + Y^2 = Z^2$), where:
$$
X = 22-2\sqrt{22} \quad\ Y = -2 + 2\sqrt{22} \quad\ Z = 24-2\sqrt{22}
$$
And the value of $\sqrt{|c-a|} + \sqrt{|a-b|}$ should be $Z + X = 46 - 4\sqrt{22}$.
N.B. We can construct any set of triplets $(a,b,c)$ as long as they satisfy the condition $a<b<c\ $ or $\ c<b<a$.

Looks great!
Also did you get $X^{2}+Y^{2}=Z^{2}$ from the fact that $-(a-b)-(b-c)=(c-a)$? Just making sure.

WLOG, we may set $c=0$ and we may assume $a=x^2, b = \pm y^2$ for some non-negative $x,y$.  With that we have
$$\sqrt{|x^2\pm y^2|}+y=20, \qquad x+y=22$$
and need to find the max of $\sqrt{|x^2\pm y^2|}+x$.
As you've noted, $x-\sqrt{|x^2\pm y^2|}=2 \implies $ we need to take the minus sign in $\pm$.  Thus
$$\sqrt{(x+y)(x-y)}+y=20, \qquad x+y=22$$
$$\implies \sqrt{22(22-2y)}+y=20 \implies  y=2\sqrt{22}-2 $$
where we have taken the non-negative root of the quadratic in $y$.
$$\implies \sqrt{|x^2\pm y^2|}+x =20-y+x=42-2y=46-4\sqrt{22}$$
